# MS ACCESS: Move ALL RECORD DATA from Table to another Table using button form

Tags: ms-access-2013

How can I move ALL RECORDS FROM TABLE 1 TO TABLE 2 in a Form using button and without selecting each data, just move only all records to another table. Anyone how to do this?

I use

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 ...
   SELECT ... FROM TABLE 1 WHERE ...
```

but it just said that it only insert one row. What I want to do is Insert All Records (All Rows) to Table 2. Please help me.

Picture: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwvLW.jpg)

Comment: Simply remove the WHERE clause. -- Note: the need to do this is usually a smell of bad database design.

Comment: @Andre thank you so much it really works. 